# SFTP connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, sshd

So yesterday I wanted to developed directly into my /var/www folder and made a few steps according to some sites. I first added my user to www-data group and changed ownership to /var/www. Right now everything is set like `755 <username>:www-data`. Additionally I made some changes to ssh_config and added `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` and

```
Match group sftp
X11Forwarding no
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I restarted the service and I was all working nice. Today (the PC was asleep) I get all my connections refused.

Im running ubuntu 12.04lts on Vbox. Host OS is Win 8 pro.

Can any1 help me solve this issue so I can ssh to my VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging in again after restarting sshd with the new configuration, to verify that the configuration really works?

It looks like ChrootDirectory requires that the chrooted-to directory be owned by root. sshd is probably checking that and refusing to allow the login, else it cause a security problem.

This article is from debian, but it should be relevant regardless:
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590

Comment: I didnt try to login back but I was able to save files from my editor via SFTP

Comment: If the editor had an established sftp session, the changed configuration wouldn't have applied - this is by design: you open a bunch of login sessions, change the configuration, and try to log-in again on a new terminal; if you messed up, you still have the established logins there to fix it.

Comment: I did a recursive chmod root:www-data and nothing :(

Comment: Even if the connection is not persistent/

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config - "This path, and all its components, must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.". Looks like you can't have it owned by www-data, or at least be writable by it.

Comment: that kinda sucks since its a wordpress folder and it needs www-data be able to write for updates :?

Comment: Well, if you're serving /home/louiev/wordpress, and you chroot to %h, then only /home/louiev needs to be root-owned; /home/louiev/wordpress can remain owned by www-data still.

Comment: Makes sense but am a bit confused now, so I ask is %h == /var/www or ~/

Comment: %h is the home directory of the user logging in.

Comment: meh still nothing not even putty I think ill just make a symlink

Comment: Putty won't let you in because there are no login binaries in the chroot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32854/discussion-between-louiev-and-antiduh)